# How to store textbox value in variable?

Tags: javascript

Here is my script:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('btnone').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnone').value;
        });
        document.getElementById('btntwo').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btntwo').value;
        });
</script>
```

So now please tell me after displaying values entered by button clicks in textbox, how can i store these values in variables?

Comment: elaborate your question .. variable means what? for what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
    var value1= "", value2=""; 
        document.getElementById('btnone').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnone').value;
     value1 = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
        });
        document.getElementById('btntwo').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btntwo').value;
     value2 = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
     <script>
    var val1,val2; // this is global scope you can use in onload, addEventListener, or in any places of JavaScript of this frame. 
        window.onload = function () {
//if you define two varaibles `var val1,val2;` here they are local to onload and also available for  addEventListener function only.
            var tb = document.getElementById('textBox');
            document.getElementById('btnone').addEventListener('click', function () {
                tb.value = val1 = tb.value + this.value;
            });
            document.getElementById('btntwo').addEventListener('click', function () {
                tb.value = val2 = tb.value + this.value;
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: why to declare this val1 and val2 on the global scope ?

Comment: just for understanding why not to define?

Comment: if you use strict mode it has to be defined. it is good to always to define them. so that it is easy to other programmer work on in large scale apps like our office app

Comment: @raghavendra: implying using the global scope is a best practice is dangerously misleading...

Comment: @LaurentS. i too know that it is for explaining the question not for real scenarios. have you read the question??

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var onestore,twostore;
    window.onload = function () {

        document.getElementById('btnone').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnone').value;
onestore=document.getElementById('textBox').value;
        });
        document.getElementById('btntwo').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btntwo').value;
twostore=document.getElementById('textBox').value;
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just to declare variables, you can use this : (the variables are not in the global scope and should not be there)

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('btnone').addEventListener('click', function () {
            var btnOneWithTextBox = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnone').value
            document.getElementById('textBox').value = btnOneWithTextBox;
        });
        document.getElementById('btntwo').addEventListener('click', function () {
            var btnTwoWithTextBox = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btntwo').value;
            document.getElementById('textBox').value = btnTwoWithTextBox;
        });
    }
</script>
```

if you would like to access it outside the events then create a variable outside this function, its all depeneds on what scope do you want this variables ?

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var btnsText;
        document.getElementById('btnone').addEventListener('click', function () {
            btnsText.btnOneWithTextBox = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnone').value
            document.getElementById('textBox').value = btnsText.btnOneWithTextBox;
        });
        document.getElementById('btntwo').addEventListener('click', function () {
            btnsText.btnTwoWithTextBox = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btntwo').value;
            document.getElementById('textBox').value = btnsText.btnTwoWithTextBox;
        });

        //here i can create other events that will use btnsText
    }
</script>
```